# Biblatex .lbx files with babel or polyglossia: not getting non-standard lbx to load

Tags: biblatex, babel, polyglossia

I've been trying to solve a bug with a custom style. It relates to `.lbx` files, and specifically how they interact with `babel` and `polyglossia`.

Here's what I have in MWE terms:

1. A simple `.lbx` file, called `english-rev.lbx`. All it does is redefine the date macros, simply for testing purposes.
2. A test file which contains the lines `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-rev}` and `\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{english-rev}` which as I understand it should tell `biblatex` that it should find the language-specific definitions in `english-rev.lbx` rather than its default files.

If I compile that test the requisite number of times without any explicit use of `babel`, I get what I expected: my default language (I guess) is English, and `biblatex` duly loads `english-rev.lbx` and we are good: the revised date macro is used.

Similarly, if I load `babel` with an explicit choice of `english`, it seems to work.

But what I really want is to deal with `british`. Now if I `\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{english-rev}` and load `babel` with a chosen language of `british`, it doesn't work. My log file shows that `english-rev` is duly being loaded:

```
(./english-rev.lbx
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english' -> 'english-rev'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english-rev.lbx' found. 
 (./english-rev.lbx
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)))
```

That I think is all as I would hope: `english-rev.lbx` should load some definitions from `english.lbx`.

But then it goes back and loads the (default) `british.lbx` again:

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'british'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'british.lbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/british.lbx
File: british.lbx 2016/05/14 v3.4 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)
```

And in doing so (I'm assuming) it "clobbers" the revised definitions from the revised file.

Does anyone know what's happening or what I'm doing wrong. I'm obviously missing something simple, but I don't know what it is. I get the same results with `polyglossia`.

The example below includes `filecontents` to generate a sample `.bib` file and the revised `.lbx` file. What it **should** do is show "(LONG DATE)" instead of 2008 in the bibliography, not any actual date. Obviously that is simply for testing purposes: what I really want is a different date format -- but my concern right now is simply to induce `biblatex` to use the `.lbx` file I want it to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
  @article{booky,
    author = "A N Author",
    title  = "A Title",
    journaltitle = "Some Journal",
    date = "2008-11-11",
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{english-rev.lbx}
\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
\DeclareBibliographyExtras{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{% %
    LONG-DATE}
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    SHORT DATE}
}
\InheritBibliographyStrings{english}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
%\usepackage[british]{babel} <-- If this is uncommented, it breaks
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-rev}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{english-rev}
\addbibresource{testbib.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{booky}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Imho you will have to create a "british-rev" (and an "american-rev") which inherit their strings from british, at least this is how biblatex-apa does it.

Comment: Ulrike, that seems to work! I have to admit that's a huge surprise; I cannot for the life of me understand why it should, and it's not clear to me whether `biblatex` cares about the inheritance or the name of the file, or both, or why! I'd love someone to explain *why* it works, but I'll happily take working without comprehension. If you'd like to make it an answer ...

Comment: We are currently trying to overhaul `.lbx` loading, the planned changes should resolve the weird behaviour here, I hope. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/677. Testing and comments are very much appreciated since the changes are to a critical part of `biblatex`'s infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

`biblatex` 3.11 has overhauled the `.lbx` loading (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/702) so that the example in your question now gives the expected results.

In earlier versions `biblatex` would not follow up on language mapping aliases when loading nested `.lbx` files and in other weird situations when an alias had been resolved before. The `.lbx` loading should hopefully be more robust now.

The changes have been tested as extensively as possible with the resources available and calls for testing before the release on comp.text.tex have not unearthed any new problems. In case you happen to stumble upon a problem related to language loading, do not hesitate to report the issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues